# The transient database snapshot for database XXXXX (database ID 8) has been marked suspect due to an IO operation failure

Tags: sql-server, database-integrity

I am having OLA hallengren job for the DBCC checks

When the job runs as per the schedule iam getting below error

The transient database snapshot for database XXXXX (database ID 8) has been marked suspect due to an IO operation failure.

In the error log log i can see below errors

> The operating system returned error 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation) to SQL Server during a write at offset 0x00002fc8f40000 in file 'L:\MSSQL10_50.PSPAC01\MSSQL\DATA\XXXXX.ndf:MSSQL_DBCC10'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> The operating system returned error 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation) to SQL Server during a write at offset 0x00006a63e28000 in file 'R:\MSSQL10_50.PSPAC01\MSSQL\DATA\XXXXX.ndf:MSSQL_DBCC10'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> NOTE: But when i manually run the same job it is running fine

I have checked the DEFRAGMENTAION for both the drives but output is stating that "no need to do the defragmentation"

How can this issue be fixed, below is the link for the image
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the error messages in the sql server error log? This error can also occur when the database is quite busy and you run dbcc check.. What else is running on the same time/schedule as or dbcc check? I'd suggest moving it to a slightly different time, as a quick first step

Comment: Below are the error message in the errorlog

Comment: The operating system returned error 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation) to SQL Server during a write at offset 0x00006a63e28000 in file 'R:\MSSQL10_50.PSPAC01\MSSQL\DATA\XXXXX.ndf:MSSQL_DBCC10'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDBThis error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online

Comment: Nothing is running at the time of DBCC

Comment: *I have checked the DEFRAGMENTAION for both the drives but output is stating that "no need to do the defragmentation"* Your disk drives or controller is probably in bad shape, defrag is miles away from what you need to do.

Comment: so what needs to be checked before doing disk defrag??